# Clear rows in knockout.js Cart Editor example

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, cart

I am trying the knockout js example of cart editor given [here](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/cartEditor.html)

I want to delete all the rows added by the user as soon as the java script alert comes. I thought setting the cartLine array to nothing would do the job but it didn't work. I tried this:

```
    self.save = function() {
    cartLine([])
    var dataToSave = $.map(self.lines(), function(line) {
        return line.product() ? {
          productName: line.product().name,
          quantity: line.quantity()
        } : undefined
    });
    alert("THANK YOU FOR YOUR ORDER!");  
};
```

But it didn't help. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.

Update:

```
self.save = function() {
  var dataToSave = $.map(self.lines(), function(line) {
    return line.product() ? {
      productName: line.product().name,
      quantity: line.quantity()
    } : undefined
  });
  self.lines([]);
  self.addLine = function() { self.lines.push(new CartLine()) };
 alert("THANK YOU FOR YOUR ORDER!");
  self.addLine = function() { self.lines.push(new CartLine()) }; //didn't work
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lines` field of the `Cart` object contains all cart lines. It's used to generate `dataToSave`, then you can clear it:

```
self.save = function() {
var dataToSave = $.map(self.lines(), function(line) {
    return line.product() ? {
      productName: line.product().name,
      quantity: line.quantity()
    } : undefined
});
self.lines([]); // clear cart lines
alert("THANK YOU FOR YOUR ORDER!");
self.addLine(); // add a new line
```

Comment: Basically what i wanted to do is clear all the rows and immediately add one more row to it. Your code works fine except that it leave only the table header and not a single row. Is there any workaround for that? I tried adding immediately after clearing but it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: And how did you do that?

Comment: You are redefining `addLine` with what you wrote. You just need to call it, it is already defined within the viewmodel (same level as self.save). Answer edited.

Comment: From what you did, it appears that you should study the basics of javascript (function, scope, object, ...) before attacking knockout (imho).